# Use Git LFS with a normal server (Server which does not implement Git LFS API)

Tags: git, github

From [here](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/docs/api.md) it said to use LFS I need a server that implements Git LFS API.

Is there any configuration or workaround so that I can use LFS with normal git server through http protocol?

Comment: You have the 'github' tag on this question (but github, of course, supports git-lfs.)  To be clear: you aren't trying to use git-lfs with github?

Comment: I am using git-lif with github Enterprise, which it seems it does not implement the Git LFS API